# C Dynamic Array has unknown values in it when passed through a function?

Tags: c

I print the array at two different locations in this program: In the main and in PrintRange.

These are the values printed initially:
[Print in main()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LAiC.png)

These are the values printed in the PrintRange function:
[Print in PrintRange()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCgpV.png)

Why are there random garbage values being printed? How do I remove them?
How do I avoid this in the future?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define WORD_LENGTH 4
#define DEF_SIZE 15

int StringToInt(char* string)
{
    int i, digit;
    int num = 0;
    int length = 0;
    //Find the length
    while(*string != '\0' && *string != '\n')
    {
        length++;
        string++;
    }
    //Start from the least significant digit
    string--;
    for(i = 0; i< length; i++)
    {
        digit = (int) (*string - '0');
        num += pow(10,i)*digit;
        string--;
    }
    return num;
}

void PrintRange(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit, int *data, int length)
{
    int i;
    int xCount = 0;
    switch(lowerLimit)
    {
        case 0 ... 9:
            printf("%d  : ", lowerLimit);
            break;
        case 10 ... 99:
            printf("%d : ", lowerLimit);
            break;
        case 100:
            printf("%d: ", lowerLimit);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%d: ", lowerLimit);
            break;
    }
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("Second values = %d\n",data[i]);
        if(data[i]>= lowerLimit && data[i]<= upperLimit)
        {
            xCount++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<xCount;i++)
    {
        printf("X");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char filename[DEF_SIZE];
    char dataPoint[4];
    int length = DEF_SIZE;
    int i, lowerLimit, upperLimit;
    int* data = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    FILE* filePtr;

    printf("Enter filename:\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    filePtr = fopen(filename,"r");

    while(fgets(dataPoint, 4, filePtr) != NULL)
    {
        if(i == length)
        {
            length += 10;
            data = realloc(data, length * sizeof(int));
        }
        data[i] = StringToInt(dataPoint);
        printf("First values = %d\n",data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    length = i;

    for(i=0; i<= 110; i++)
    {
        if(i%10 == 0)
            lowerLimit = i;
        else if(i%10 == 9)
        {
            upperLimit = i;
            PrintRange(lowerLimit, upperLimit, data, length);
        }
    }
    free(data);
    fclose(filePtr);
}
```

Comment: What is `i` set to in the while loop in main()?  You never assign it any value and then you use it.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized and that is enough to invoke Undefined Behaviour. Add `i=0;` before the loop in main.

Comment: Are you aware that `StringToInt()` can be replaced with the standard function [strtol](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/es/man3/strtol.3.html)?

Comment: Please add your output as formatted text to the question. There is no need to provide plain text as images.

Answer (score -1):

First rule in C - initialise variables before use!

You don't appear to initialise any of the arrays that you declare before they are used.

```
char filename[DEF_SIZE];
char dataPoint[4];
int* data = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int));
```

you should set their default data e.g. `memset(data,0, length*sizeof(int));`, immediately after the `malloc` statement.